# Custom context menu XAML for WP8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I try to implement a custom ContextMenu in a `LongListSelector`.

I'm not using the `ContextMenu` from `Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit`, it's basically the same as in the Rowi App:

[image]
<sub>(source: [hiddenpineapple.com](http://static.hiddenpineapple.com/images/rowi-phone.png))</sub>

### Approach 1

My list item toggles a VisualState on hold and an overlay is shown with controls in it.

#### The problem

I can't find a way to go back to the default state when the user clicks outside of the list item (as in the default ContextMenu).

### Approach 2

I've implemented a custom template for the toolkit ContextMenu which looks exactly the same. I had to move its margin top to `-itemHeight`, as by default it is below the item.

#### The problem

The problem with this solution is, that it automatically closes itself when opening and I couldn't figure out how to avoid this.

Another problem was that it didn't work well with `TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled` from the Toolkit (visual problems).

### I need your help

Any suggestions on how to get this working?

---

## Answer

Thanks to [Cheese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235287/cheese), now I know how to properly close the menu when the user clicks outside.
His suggestion was to get the coordinates of a Tap event on the current page, and check if it's inside the menu. When not, close the menu.

So I added a Tap listener to the page when the menu opens, and removed it when the menu closes. From the page listener I got the event coordinates and could check if it's inside the control which holds the menu (same size and position). I received the position of the control with `Point leftUpperPoint = control.TransformToVisual(page).Transform(new Point(0, 0))` and the `rightLowerPoint` by adding the ActualWidth and ActualHeight.

#### But then I realized:

Why should I even calculate if the tap is inside the menu? I always want to close the menu when the user taps anywhere on the screen. If it's outside, *yes*. If it's on a menu button, *yes*.

Another modification I made was to listen for `MouseLeftButtonDown` instead of `Tap` as it also triggers when the user swipes.

So I removed this code and came up with the following:

```
private void ToggleMenu(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
  PhoneApplicationFrame frame = ((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual);
  VisualState state = this.States.CurrentState;

  if (state == null || state.Name == "DefaultState")
  {
    frame.MouseLeftButtonDown += MouseDownDelegate;
    this.State = "MenuState";
  }
  else
  {
    frame.MouseLeftButtonDown -= MouseDownDelegate;
    this.State = "DefaultState";
  }
}

private void MouseDownDelegate(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  ToggleMenu(sender, null);
}
```

This works perfectly!

Thanks to [Cheese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2235287/cheese) for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1 problem

The best solution would be:

Get the menus coordinates, when user makes a tap - you check are tap coordinates on menu or not, if not - dissmiss - simple.

Approach 2 problem

I guess you had some button in a corner and when you tapped on it - nothing happened? And when you dissmissed the Tilt all worked. It seems that tilt works faster than a click, so, tilt changes the button coordinates, and device thiks you have missed/or dragged off

Comment: I've edited my question as my response was to long for a comment. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this by @denniscode http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/rowi-show-tap-menu

Comment: Sadly this can't fulfil my requirement. I already know how to toggle a overlay menu. What I need is the auto-closing feature on outside click. But thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

You can use what @ScottIsAFool suggested and maybe create another Dependency Property on your TapMenu control of type UIElement named CloseWhenTappedElement and automatically listen for Tap events inside your control once set. For example

```
<Grid x:Name="TapArea"/>
<TapMenu CloseWhenTappedElement="{Binding ElementName=TapArea"}/>
```